# how to add Tkinter support to python2 on my gentoo?

Tags: python, tkinter, gentoo

The default python version on my gentoo is python2,
and the default python installed on gentoo has no Tkinter support.
After I added the following line to /etc/portage/package.use

```
dev-lang/python tk
```

then emerge python, it only shows:
[ebuild   R    ] dev-lang/python-3.1.3-r1  USE="examples gdbm ipv6 ncurses readline sqlite ssl threads tk (wide-unicode) xml -build -doc -wininst" 0 kB

There is no python2!....

How to add Tkinter support to python2?

Comment: Is there a separate tkinter package? I'm not familiar with Gentoo, but on Ubuntu, you need `python-tk` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to explicitly specify the Python version you want to install, e.g. `emerge =python-2.7.2-r2`?